# MySQL ORDER BY Optimization on Multiple Joins

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, join, sql-order-by

I need some help optimizing some queries for my database. I do understand the use of indexes in helping with joins and order by statements to help speed things up, but I was wondering if there were some techniques available to avoid using filesort and using temporary when I use the EXPLAIN command. Here's an example of what I am using.

```
SELECT a.id, DATE_FORMAT(a.submitted_at, '%d-%b-%Y') as submitted_at, a.user_id,
            data1.*, 
            data2.name, data2.type,
            u.first_name, u.last_name               
            FROM applications AS a 
            LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = a.user_id
            LEFT JOIN score_table AS data1 ON data1.applications_id = a.id
            LEFT JOIN sections AS data2 ON data2.id = data1.section_id
            WHERE category_id = [value] && submitted_at IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY data2.type
```

Again, indexes are being used properly in my queries like the one up above. If I take out the ORDER BY clause, then the query executes quickly from using the proper indexes. I understand that the order of the joins can affect the performance of the query. When I test using the ORDER BY on the users table, since it is the next table after the "const", it will only use "Using where, Using Filesort" on EXPLAIN. If I drop to any of the other tables, we get into the "Using Temporary" issue.

My question is: what would be the best way to optimize queries like this to run faster and in the best case scenario, avoid using filesort/temporary in EXPLAIN? I'm open to any possibilities :) I'm more or less interested in the theory on how to make queries like this perform better, than this exact query as I am having to perform more and more of these deep level ORDER BY queries in the database I'm working on.

--EDIT--

Here's the explain of the query above.....

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys               key         key_len     ref                 rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          a       ref     category_id,submitted_at    category_id     4           const               49      Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          u       eq_ref  PRIMARY                     PRIMARY     4           a.user_id           1   
1   SIMPLE          data1   ref     app id                      app id      4           a.id                7   
1   SIMPLE          data2   eq_ref  PRIMARY                     PRIMARY     4           data1.section_id    1
```

Comment: Do you have `indexes` on fields in `join conditions` and on fields in `where` clausule and on fields in `order by` ?

Comment: @piotrekkr Yes I do (all of the above), I just edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: Since you ORDER BY on a table that is LEFT JOINed, you will not be able to bypass creation of a temp table. This is, because MySQL can't drive the query from the same table, that it orders by.

Comment: Provide tables scheme and `explain` results it would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things.

1. Are you sure you need to use 'LEFT JOIN'? Looking at the query it looks like you can get away with 'INNER JOIN' which will reduce the number of potential rows.
2. You didn't post your schema, but I assume that users.id, applications.user_id, score_table.applications_id, applications.id, sections.id and score_table.section_id are all ints? If they are non-ints I would strongly urge you to convert them. And if not primary keys, be sure they are indexed.
3. I wouldn't run any mysql level data formatting (i.e. DATE_FORMAT), as it will create some overhead during the query, rather I would format data like this at the app layer.
4. The ORDER BY forces MySQL to create a temp table in order to sort correctly, so be sure you absolutely need this functionality. If so, be sure that sections.type is indexed.
5. I would consider using a different alias naming convention. data1 and data2 are so abstract it's difficult to discern what they are actually referring to. I would suggest you use an abbreviated construct of the table you are aliasing, for example; applications becomes app (instead of a), score_table becomes score (instead of data1), etc.

Comment: 1. Yeah, I'm thinking about staying with LEFT JOINs. It does pull the data correctly and just what I need.
2. Yes, they are all ints.
3. That's something to keep in the back of my mind definitely. Thanks for the tip.
4. Yeah, I absolutely need the functionality because the data must be sorted by a particular field and that field is usually a few levels deep.
5. I only named the tables this way just for example.
Thanks!

Comment: @ImmortalFirefly: You may want to consider removing the submitted_at in the where clause and then run the explain, I think this is what is causing your query to resort to filesort. If so, try adding a composite index for category_id and submitted_at.

Comment: I tried altering the query to ORDER BY a.id (the primary key) and I still got filesort even after removing the DATE_FORMAT() on submitted_at

Comment: @ImmortalFirefly: No I meant remove the '&& submitted_at IS NOT NULL' from the WHERE clause, I believe it's what is causing the query to consider the submitted_at field, which may be causing the use temp and use filesort flags. We can add it back, was just trying to identify the culprit.

Comment: @ImmortalFirefly: What did the issue end up being?

Comment: I still haven't figured it out, but since you made the effort to give a good answer and provided follow up, marking yours as the answer was the best was to rep you up :) I'll let you know if I figure it out.